# Display Transparent Image in Qlabel over a QAxWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlabel

I'm trying to display a transparent .png image over a QAxWidget (Web Browser). However, I cannot see the image. Just a black solid box. I have loaded the image using the pixmap property in the GUI (the same image is also added to the qrc file as well). Here is the initialization code of the Qlabel

```
ui->lblCh->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
ui->lblCh->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
ui->lblCh->repaint();
```

I'm using Qt 5.2.1 with Win7 32-bit